# Opening database connections in parallel

Tags: database, database-connection

If a `MySQL` database connection is already open from a script (say `PHP`), is it advisable for another script (say `python`) to access the same database table at the the same time? 
If not, what should be the alternative?

Comment: Database systems like MySQL are designed to accommodate this kind of  multi-user access.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks.. that helps.. I was gonna make a python script to access a database table that my php script is currently accessing. I wanted to make sure its advisable before I proceeded making it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database systems like MySQL are designed to accommodate this kind of multi-user access. They do this by employing locking mechanisms, most of which work in the background.  The locking mechanisms prevent one user from trying to read a record while someone else is writing it, or two users from writing the same record at once.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html